# How to write a test case for RecyclerView using Espresso in android..?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm new for android testing. How to write test case for RecyclerView using Espresso Framework. Where my RecyclerView has a click listener and when click a item it passes intent to another activity. Please help me to write test case for this.

Answer (score 1):

To click an item in RecyclerView:

See more on [Espresso RecyclerView testing](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/lists/index.html#recyclerviews)

```
onView(withId(R.id.scroll_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(3, click()));
```

To check if Intent is sent:

```
// to the "phone" activity has been sent.
intended(toPackage("com.android.phone"));
```

see more on [Espresso Intent testing](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/)